# Istio : HTTPS Traffic between Pods working only if sidecar not injected

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, https, istio, istio-sidecar

Steps i have done  :

- I have two namespaces one with istio injected and another not
- Now deploy simple nginx server using this yaml in both namespace

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: software-upgrader
  labels:
    app: software-upgrader
    service: software-upgrader
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 25301
  selector:
    app: software-upgrader
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: software-upgrader
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: software-upgrader
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: software-upgrader
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/mesh7-public-images/scalability/nginx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: software-upgrader
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 20m
            memory: 32Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 20m
            memory: 32Mi
```

- now deploy HTTPS servers in both namespaces by this steps [Steps to deploy HTTPS server](https://github.com/ChocolatePadmanaban/DevOps-Notes/tree/main/Servers/HTTPS_Servers)
- now curl it from another pod in both namespace
- The Pod with istio not injected would get 200 OK , while istio-injected pod would get

```
curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:1409445C:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv13 alert certificate required, errno 0
command terminated with exit code 56
```

- Pardon me of my ignorance do i have to create some Service-entry or Virtual Service for HTTPS to happen between Pods in same namespace to happen if istio is injected?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add Protocol to Service port Definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-https-server
  labels:
    app: test-https-server
    service: test-https-server
spec:
  ports:
    - name: test-https
      port: 25302
      appProtocol: https
  selector:
    app: test-https-server
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-https-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-https-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-https-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/mesh7-public-images/scalability/nginx
        command: ["bash", "-c", "python3 ThreadedHTTPSServer.py 25302"]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: test-https-server
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 20m
            memory: 32Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 20m
            memory: 32Mi
```

This has a example of working example

```
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 25302
      appProtocol: https # Should Specify Protocol
```

[Istio appProtocol configuration doc](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/)